How to plot the range of the solution of the inequal equations in Matlab?
Maybe plot the range of the solution of the inequal equations in Matlab is not difficult, but it may not be easy. Is there a way to achieve that? For example, how to plot the range of the solution of the equations

1/2x>=y;
3/2x<=y;
x-6=-y;

In Matlabe, these codes may be useful, but they are not right and there are too trivial. Is there a way to make them simple?
% Define the range
x = linspace(-10, 10, 500); % Range for x
y = linspace(-10, 10, 500); % Range for y

% Create a grid
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);

% Define inequality conditions
condition1 = Y <= 0.5 * X;       % 1/2x >= y  ->  y <= 1/2x
condition2 = Y >= 1.5 * X;       % 3/2x <= y  ->  y >= 3/2x
condition3 = Y == -X + 6;        % x - 6 = -y  ->  y = -x + 6

% Combine conditions to find the solution region
solution_region = condition1 & condition2;

% Plot
figure;
hold on;

% Plot the solution region satisfying all inequalities
contourf(X, Y, solution_region, [1 1], 'FaceColor', 'cyan', 'EdgeColor', 'none');

% Plot the boundaries
plot(x, 0.5 * x, 'r', 'LineWidth', 1.5); % Boundary for y = 1/2x
plot(x, 1.5 * x, 'b', 'LineWidth', 1.5); % Boundary for y = 3/2x
plot(x, -x + 6, 'g', 'LineWidth', 1.5);  % Boundary for y = -x + 6

% Beautify the plot
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
title('Solution Region for the System of Inequalities');
legend({'Solution Region', 'y = 1/2x', 'y = 3/2x', 'y = -x + 6'}, 'Location', 'best');
grid on;
xlim([-10, 10]);
ylim([-10, 10]);
hold off;



Check this MuPAD package for now. It's not recommendable at all to use symbolic variables when all you want is to plot a few things. When I get a chance, I'll post something different. Or maybe someone else will beat me to it.

Also, pleasesimplify the problem into a minimal example. You need to formulate the question with the simplest function that can represent what you want to do.

The other thing is, a large part of your question is really a math problem. Even when I come back, I won't be giving any math tutorials. That would be off-topic on SO.

@Argyll If I do not use Mupad, can I solve this? I know that the 'solve' can solve inqual equations, but the answer are about u,v which are not expressed by bt and Td.

There is a lot of things that make no sense in your code: Why are you using symbolic variables if you want to plot your data with imshow, imshow can only plot an image containing numbers only. Why are you creating 2 symbolics variables (bt and Td) but then you overwrite thoses variables with a matrix. A determinant always output one single value but you're using it as it output a 2D matrix in order to create a logical mask. At the moment it's unclear what you're asking and this question cannot be answered, as asked by @Argyll please provide a minimal and complete example.

@obchardonob  I have changed my codes.

@Y.zeng: solving inequality needs to be its separate question. For plotting, the idea of plotting in Matlab is that it plots individual points -- whether 2D or 3D. Matlab further has facilities to interpolate between the scatter points pending what on you need. It can start with simple straight lines between points and it has more sophisticated spline functions. In other words, you need to solve your inequality first. Once you know either the analytical solutions or numeric approximates, you can then plot your solutions.

@Y.zeng: And I hope you understand why contributors at SO, including myself, persistently ask you to provide minimal examples, among other improvements we also ask for. Solving your exact problem is none of our jobs and does not help anyone but you. But if you can identify a general problem and in a basic form, your problem now can be of help to many others in the future. That's why contributors contribute on SO. It's not a free outsourcing site.

@Argyll Thanks for  your kind reason. I have updated my question. Hope you have time to check that again.
